# Python: how to read json file and export to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, angularjs, json, python-2.7

My backend code using Python 2.7 able to convert from dataframe to json using `df.to_json()`but I need to export this json file into MySQL database since frontend code using angular 2 is javascript.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
df.to_csv("abc.csv")
df.to_json("abc_json.json")
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pw@sbc.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/abc$default')
df.to_sql(name='KLSE', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Code above was run without problem but I want to MySQL database in json format so that frontend code can query.
I can not find related link in google or stackoverflow with similar issues.Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `so that frontend code can query.`?

Comment: @ Zohaib Ijaz, frontend is an android apps that need to access the MySQL database data